# Codepen.io not displaying/running code. It just says "connection was rest"

Tags: codepen

Hi everyone I'm new here. How do I display the code? I've tried with different browsers settings and it just won't display it.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14xJq.png)
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot provided lacks enough information to really be able to give much feedback on any underlying issues causing this, could you paste the html/css as code blocks on here for examination?

This can be done using the formatting settings at the top of the textarea in which you can edit your question or, more simply, by using three backticks (this symbol `) in a row both before and after your code.